Entra ID access token is not working but Id token works - Token genrated by Angular and Spring boot API
We are currently migrating Okta to Azure Entra ID.
During POC, Angular MSAL v2 library generated token and shared with backend team (Access and ID Token).
While verifying access token in the backend Spring Boot  server, getting exception 'Signature verification failed.
When passing ID token, It is passed and get the response of accessed API.
Any specific reason why only works ID token, or any extra configuration required to authorize token generated by Angular ?

You might want to validate it against the public keys path of the token provider and should be validated fine.
If it is a jwt it would be something like <provider_url>/.well-known/jwks.json.
If you need to follow up please post some trace of your error please.

How to get public key path?

Edited my answer above. hope it helps.

https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/

Hello @Sreeragh how did you solve this issue? Could you please share your solution?

@Ali I have managed to fix by adding custom scope.
